# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" error with ng-animate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-animate

After I update from 1.2.24 to 1.3.0-rc.2 I'm getting following error. When I remove `ngAnimate` from modules, it disappears. Only thing that uses animates is angular-ui-bootstrap.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at M (http://localhost/webapp/js/angular-animate.min.js:8:113)
    at http://localhost/webapp/js/angular-animate.min.js:19:6
    at http://localhost/webapp/js/angular-animate.min.js:8:29
    at m.$digest (http://localhost/webapp/js/angular.min.js:116:279)
    at m.$apply (http://localhost/webapp/js/angular.min.js:118:386)
    at l (http://localhost/webapp/js/angular.min.js:77:80)
    at u (http://localhost/webapp/js/angular.min.js:81:389)
    at XMLHttpRequest.v.onreadystatechange (http://localhost/webapp/js/angular.min.js:82:477) angular.js:10627
    (anonymous function) angular.js:10627
    (anonymous function) angular.js:7824
    m.$digest angular.js:13166
    m.$apply angular.js:13380
    l angular.js:8849
    u angular.js:9064
    v.onreadystatechange angular.js:9003
```

Thanks in advance for any help...

**Edit:**

After block by block examination, I found out that accordion causes the error. But it still works and animation is also ok. But it's annoying to have errors.

Comment: Did you update to the newest version of ui-bootstrap with it? It might be worth looking at the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) too, to see if there are any changes to `ngAnimate` that might be tripping it up.

Comment: Both are the latest versions. I've checked changelog already but couldn't find a breaking change...

Comment: Issue reported here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9049 and might be fixed with https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/8958

Answer (score 1):

would need more infos but a solution could be

[ngAnimate]=... instead of * ngAnimate.